# Error opening dashboards

Tags: dashboard, reports-api

One among four users with the same profile and Role is having an issue in viewing the dashboards. When the user clicks on the dashboards there is an error encountered.

Error: This report cannot be used as the source for this component. If it is a summary or matrix report, add one or more groupings in the report. If it is a tabular report with a row limit, specify the Dashboard Settings in the report.

[image]

Comment: "If it is a summary or matrix report, add one or more groupings in the report." seems like an easy fix. Can you describe your report? Are there groupings, whats the type, is it available to that user?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by updating the permissions for the user. Thanks for the help.